# Two different paths from X to Y in a graph

Tags: prolog, graph-theory, prolog-dif

I am stuck with the following Prolog question:
Given the edges of a graph with no cycles as facts. e.g:

```
edge(a, b).
edge(b, c).
edge(c, d).
edge(c, e).
...
```

I have to write a predicate that tests whether there are two different paths between vertices X and Y. e.g the call `two_paths(a, c).` should return true if there are two different paths from node a to node c. I know how to check whether there is a path between two vertices:

```
path(X, Y) :- edge(X, Y).
path(X, Y) :- edge(X, Z), path(Z, Y).
```

But how should I do this to check for two distinct paths? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An idea might be to create a predicate `path/3` that returns the constructed path, and then query for two paths that are different. Something like:

```
path(X,Y,[X,Y]) :- edge(X,Y).
path(X,Y,[X|T]) :- edge(X,Z), path(Z,Y,T).
```

Now `path(a,c,T)` will show you the path:

```
?- path(a,c,L).
L = [a, b, c] ;
false.
```

Now you could construct a predicate:

```
two_paths(X,Y) :-
    path(X,Y,La),
    path(X,Y,Lb),
    dif(La,Lb).
```

In other words, you ask Prolog to construct for you a path `La`, next construct for you a path `Lb` and then check if they are not equal (`dif(La,Lb)`). The first constructed `Lb` will be equivalent to `La`, but due to Prologs backtracking mechanism, it will try to construct you another path for which the condition might succeed. This is a rather pure Prolog implementation (with no cut (`!`), `once/1`, etc.). More efficient approaches exists since here you will "redo" the work in your second call.

A more efficient approach could be to construct a predicate `path_avoid/3` (or `path_avoid/4`) where you feed the first constructed path to the predicate and thus force your program to at least at some point perform a different step from the one presented. I leave this open as a potential exercise.

Comment: Very clear and constructive answer. Thank you very much! I'll edit my thread with the dots :-)

Comment: You might want to replace ```\=``` by ```dif/2``` -- it works for non-ground solutions too.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x: yes that's indeed a better option. Thanks.